# PostgreSQL - how to find records where the difference between two dates is greater than 1 day/month?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, where-clause, date-arithmetic

I store in a DB table orders where every order has a date column when it can be "picked up from" and a date column signaling till when it can be "picked up to".

Here's a simplified structure:

```
id | ... | pickup_from | pickup_to
1  | ... | 2020-10-15  | 2020-10-16
2  | ... | 2020-08-07  | 2020-10-16 
3  | ... | 2020-10-01  | 2020-10-03
```

I would like to find all records where range/interval between `pickup_from` and `pickup_to` is greater than 2 months. In this case, the result would be this record:

```
2  | ... | 2020-08-07  | 2020-10-16
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use date arithmetics:

```
select *
from mytable t
where pickup_to > pickup_from + interval '2 month'
```

Comment: Is the ANSI SQL interval syntax also supported, i.e. `interval '2' month`?

Comment: @jarlh: yes Postgres supports that too, although that's somehow less flexible (eg `interval '1 month 2 hour 3 seconds'`)

Answer (score 0):

Use `interval` to add a time period:

```
where pickup_to > pickup_from + interval '2 month'
```

Comment: Answers posted within the same second, it's been a while... This time my answers appears first though. I wonder whether SO actually stores the factional seconds when an answer is posted.

Comment: @GMB . . . I would be surprised if SO did *not*.  It is built on SQL Server and even `datetime` data types have fractions of a second.